# can I reset auto_increment field in mySql?

Tags: sql, mysql

Can I reset the auto-increment index of a MySQL table so that it starts counting from zero again?

I deleted all the rows in the table--how can I reset that counter as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To delete all rows from a MySQL table AND reset the auto_increment value, use the `truncate` command.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: In addition, truncate will be *significantly* faster than a delete.

Answer (score 5):

Or just truncate the table instead of deleting the roles -- that drops and re-adds the table, resetting the autoincrement values in the process

Comment: Truncate doesn't drop and re-add the table. Truncate removes all rows from a table without logging the individual row deletions. Truncate is faster and uses fewer system and transaction log resources.