# MySQL: Is there a way to reset a table?

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a way to reset a table?

I mean not only deleting all rows, but starting the auto_incrementing ID back to 0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can I reset auto_increment field in mySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529093/can-i-reset-auto-increment-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remove all data:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

To reset the auto-increment:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: As long as you're at v. 5.0.13 or later, the auto increment value is reset automatically by TRUNCATE TABLE. Prior to that it might be reset as long as there are no FKs into the truncated table (a "fast" truncate is used).

Comment: @Tom H. I am on 5.0.77 I just checked. So I just need to call the truncate line then. What are FKs?

Comment: FK = foreign keys - which are references to the primary keys of other tables